# This question is based on clock.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a clock, the time is x hours:y minutes. After 10 hours 50 minutes the time is y hours:x minutes. What is x:y?

Answer (score 1):

The way I think about it is that $x,y\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. Then with picking some starting points you can easily end up with correct answer which is 1:11.